# Parse.Installation beforeSave is not getting called

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Users,

I'm trying to set the currentUser to the Installation object. I followed code logic of the AnyPic Project but the `beforeSave` method is only get called when the App starts fresh. So if someone installs the App (ofc atm he is not authenticated) the request.user in CC is null.

So I thought I call 
`[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];` 
when the user Registered/LogIn successfully. But unfortunately the `beforeSave` is not getting called.

I know I can set it also on client-side but I would like prevent it for future.

**CC Installations beforeSave**

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    console.log("user"+request.user);
    if (request.user) {
            request.object.set('user', request.user);
        } else {
       request.object.unset('user');
    }
    response.success();
});
```

**Calling Installation update on iOS**

```
[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you call saveInBackground it doesn't even request saving the object since there are no changes made.

Instead, at client side, I set the user or unset it if user is not logged in then saveInBackground. And at CloudCode, I use beforeSave like you did to override the client's request parameters.

So all you need to do, is to put or make any changes in the [PFInstallation currentInstallation] before invoking saveInBackground.